# How can I paste img tag into stream.publish method?

Tags: facebook

I am new in Facebook API, I found only that page about fb.ui http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui . I use new `connect-js`, and when i just place in my text `<img src="/sa/asd/asd.jpg" />` slash is escaping to `\/`.
Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `media` property of `attachment` object, something like:

```
 attachment: {
   name: 'Connect',
   caption: 'The Facebook Connect JavaScript SDK',
   description: (
     'A small JavaScript library that allows you to harness ' +
     'the power of Facebook, bringing the user\'s identity, ' +
     'social graph and distribution power to your site.'
   ),
   media: [{ 
    type: 'image', 
    src: 'http://example.com/img.jpg', 
    href: 'http://example.com'
   }],
   href: 'http://github.com/facebook/connect-js'
 },
```

You can read more about attachments [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/attachments).

Comment: @John Haven't met someone who thinks it doesn't :)